Operating a Listbox that calls a second paired sheet
This is an Axtive X Listbox, and I can't seem to get the OLEForm.Object section to not error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I know the first way of launching worksheets using ListBox1.Text works, but I need to Dim and set the object for the second more complex code, and the OLEObject method isn't working.

Runtime Error 438 object doesn't support this property or method.

            Sheets(ListBox1.Text).Visible = True
            Sheets(ListBox1.Text).Activate
            Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1

        Sub ActivateSheetFromListBox()
            Dim wsIndex As Worksheet
            Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
            Dim listBox As listBox
            Dim selectedItem As String
        
            ' Get references to the worksheets and list box
'I cannot get these form controls to work OLEFormControl.Object, Or .Format. It's an active X control, not a MS Form object.
            'Set wsIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Index")
            'Set listBox = wsIndex.Shapes("ListBox1").OLEFormControl.Object
            'Set wsIndex.Shapes("Listbox1").OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex = 0
        
            ' Get the selected item from the list box
            selectedItem = listBox.ListIndex
        
            ' Get the corresponding sheet names based on the selected item
            ' Adjust the array below to match your sheet pairs
            Dim sheetPairs() As Variant
            sheetPairs = Array("LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT|LXXXXXXT-LXXXXXXB, LXXXXXXB-RXXXXXXH|RXXXXXXH-LXXXXXXB, LXXXXXXB-SXXXXXXH|SXXXXXXH-LXXXXXXB, LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXO|LXXXXXXO-LXXXXXXB")
        
            ' Activate the paired sheets and set them to the right of the "Index" sheet
            If selectedItem >= 0 And selectedItem < UBound(sheetPairs) Then
                Dim sheetPair() As String
                sheetPair = Split(sheetPairs(selectedItem), "|")
                
                wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetPair(0))
                wsTarget.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                
                ' Move the selected sheet to the right of the "Index" sheet
                wsTarget.Move After:=wsIndex
                
                wsTarget.Activate
        
                ' Activate the paired sheet and move it to the right of the selected sheet
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetPair(1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetPair(1)).Move After:=wsTarget
                'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetPair(1)).Activate
                
            End If
        End Sub


For example:
Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox
    
Set lb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Shapes("Listbox1").OLEFormat.Object.Object
Debug.Print lb.ColumnCount, lb.ListIndex

